# C# String.Substring cut out a IpAddress and a String

Tags: c#, string, substring

The following code always crashes. The input is like this:
`String 1` is a `IpAddress` (`192.168.187.815`) `string 2` should be a Port so the whole input is `192.168.187.815,2332`. The code which should cut out the ipAddress (`string 1`) and the port (`string 2`) looks like this:

```
Console.Write("String1,String2>");
string both = Console.ReadLine();
string string1 = both.Substring(0,both.IndexOf(","));
Console.WriteLine(string1.Length);
string string2 = both.Substring( string1.Length , both.Length - 1);
Console.WriteLine(string1);
Console.WriteLine(string2);
Console.Read();
```

does anyone knows why it isn't working?
I was asked for the exception so here it is.
There is one little problem I am from Germany and the exception is in German.
I tried to translate it with google translator but I think we all know its crap. well here is the original German exception `Der Index und die Länge müssen sich auf eine Position in der Zeichenfolge beziehen. Parametername: length` and here is my bad translation: `the index and the length should be specified on a position in the string. parameter : Length` I hope this make sense

Comment: `string.Split(',')` should do the trick and is easier to use. What's the exception that's thrown? ([mcve])

Comment: The answers given to you are ok, but I really recommend you use `Split` instead, it's easier and less prone to errors like the one you have

Comment: @jAC the posted code is a very good example to verify the problem, copy -> paste -> run . OP just did not state the Exception message. But the example is good

Comment: @MongZhu sorry but i dont get what you are trying to say

Comment: @jakob which part? are you talking about my comment? or my answer?

Comment: @MongZhu your comment

Comment: @jakob That comment was intended for me.

Comment: jAC pointed you towards the link, saying that you should read up on how to post a minimal and verfiable example. I said that you have done this almost already. Except that if you encounter an Exception, you should also post the content of this exception that is thrown in your code. The message of it

Comment: Oh, i see i thought someone wrote my name incorrectly. Because my name is jakob... I didnt read the whole comment section. sorry . @MongZhu one second

Comment: Good that you posted the error message. The correct translation and the message can be found [in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx) : `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear that the separator is `,` then why are you complicating things by using `Substring` why not proceed with `Split` like the following:

```
    string[] inputParams= both.Split(',');
    string ipAddress = inputParams[0];
    string portNumber =inputParams[1];
```

- Actually the second parameter of the [`String.Substring()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) method
  represents the number of characters(not the last index as you
  thought).
- If you again wish to proceed with `Substring` the you can try like the following:

  ```
  string ipAddress = both.Substring(0,both.IndexOf(","));
  string portNumber =both.Substring(both.IndexOf(",")+1)
  ```

  But still the first one is the best for this situation

Comment: This will be best method as we don't know how many characters will be in port. There might be chances that it will have only 2. Instead of `Substring` use `split`

Comment: @Lifewithsun why should it matter how many characters are either in the IP or in the port? OP is using the IndexOf the `,` like the Split method. It should only matter how many commas there are in the string.

Comment: "number of digits in the IP so processing based on length will cause the same issues again in future" why so? OP method using IndexOf has almost the same approach as Split, because it aims for the comma as separator. If done correctly it does not matter how long the IP can become.

Comment: @MongZhu: Yep you are correct, I was misleaded by the first comment, thank you anyway have a look at my updates

Comment: @MongZhu Sorry I have considered whole string so i have written the comment. As per @un-lucky latest edit it looks fine. As we passing length parameter as `IndexOf(",") will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

the second parameter of [String.Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) denotes the length of the substring or the number of characters that you want to pull from the string.

> length
>   Type: System.Int32
>   The number of characters in the substring.

Your solution would be to subtract the start index from the `both.Length`. This way you get the number of characters between the `,` and the end of the entire string `both`

```
string string2 = both.Substring(string1.Length+1, both.Length - 1-string1.Length);
```

Also note that you should take the start index +1 if you want to avoid the `,` in your string/portnumber.

Another possibility would be to use the [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) method to split at the separator `,`. It will return an `string[]` and you can easily assign the values:

```
string both = "192.168.187.815,2332";
string[] splitted = both.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string string1 = splitted[0];
string string2 = splitted[1];


Console.WriteLine(string1);
Console.WriteLine(string2);
```

Disclaimer: this solution implies strongly that you really have an input string in the format `"something,someting"` otherwise you might run into an index out of bounds. You should check the length of the array `splitted` before accessing hard coded indexes!

Comment: Both answers the question as to why it isn't working & adds the suggested improvement.

Comment: yes, both qouestions are awnsering the question. i took the one from un-lucky because i saw his one first.

Comment: @jakob no problem, the accepting decision is yours :) I just wonder because the other answer that you saw first was posted 3 minutes later than mine :)